# In Angular, how to implement button:focus outline: none in a directive

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive, angular2-directives

In my css file, i make outline: none to my button.

```
.my-btn:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

Now i want to create a Directive to my button which also will do this. How to write such a directive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive and have a @HostListener on focus/fousin based on your requirement

*@HostListener('focus')*

and use ElementRef to set *nativeElement.style.outline = none;*

Answer (score 0):

- Create your custom directive by using `ng g d unfocus-btn`
- Write the following code in UnfocusButtonDirective.ts;

`@Directive({   selector: '[unfocus]' })`

```
export class UnfocusButtonDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('focus')
  private onButtonFocus() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.outline = 'none';
  }

}
```

- Use in HTML where you want that directive

`<button type="button" unfocus >Submit</button>`   // Add you directive here

- Declare your directive in nearest module.ts file or in app.module.ts file

`@NgModule({ declarations: [UnfocusButtonDirective] })`

That's it. All set.